# How to measure power consumption of pulsed DC motor correctly?

Tags: current-measurement, watts, rms

I built a **permanent magnet pulsed DC motor**, and am trying to accurately measure power input, which proves to be harder than expected.

The motor is pulsed with a **25% duty cycle** square wave and powered by a **24V battery**.

Normally, Power = Volts * Amps, but that does not take the duty cycle into account.

On top of that, the rotating permanent magnets induce a **counter EMF**, and the *difference* between the applied battery voltage and the counter EMF is what determines how much current flows through the windings.

This means the current waveform is no longer a square wave, as I tried to illustrate below:

[image: Current waveform]

One research officer from an electric company mentioned the following:

[image]

However, it seems to me that the *average* current `Iav` already takes both the ON and OFF current into account, so why would you still need to multiply by the duty cycle?

How would *you* accurately measure the power input into a permanent magnet pulsed DC motor?

Thanks!!

Comment: To get the correct units of power, a multiplication voltage duty cycle seems appropriate. voltage duty cycle is a measure of the average voltage, which when multiplied by the average current is probably taken as an indicator of power.

Comment: For sinusoidal wave forms average and RMS are different numbers. Are you sure that you get the power by using average current for this situation ?

Comment: how accurate? does a shunt and analog multiplier not suffice for instantaneous power?

Answer (score 2):

Average current does take both the ON and OFF current into account ... but if there is OFF current, it flows during the time when you are supplying 0V not 24V.

Multiplying by the duty cycle correctly accounts for this variation in the supply voltage.

An example where this is accurate is PWM switching a voltage source via an inductor, in other words, a buck convertor.

It's probably the most reasonably accurate technique back in the days of electric typewriters or daisywheel printers when that letter was written; nowadays you'd sample both current and voltage well above the Nyquist frequency and compute an accurate average power using DSP.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! So you're saying that the formula in the letter works, but that with modern meters you can simply measure and multiply voltage and current to get power in? Should I use DC or RMS measurements?

Comment: Perhaps not modern meters; but modern digital scopes can generally do the work for you. (Failing that; dump their traces into a spreadsheet and process the data there!)

Answer (score 0):

You do measure true RMS value of the voltage and current. If the PWM frequency is enough high, then every good (I have to emphasize 'good', not a cheap Ali instrument) would measure it. Else you would need to integrate / square / mean with ADC & DSP (or MCU) with lots of memory and CPU speed. The BEMF doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Normally, Power = Volts * Amps, but that does not take the duty cycle
> into account.

It does if you measure *average* power.

The normal method of measuring DC motor power consumption is to supply it with a fixed voltage and measure the average supply current. This is accurate (no 'rms' measurements or duty cycle calculations required) except that it doesn't take controller losses into account - which can be significant when applying PWM.

To get better accuracy you could measure power at the motor itself, but this requires a **power** meter that is accurate when dealing with high frequency waveforms. Just measuring rms current and voltage is not enough. The meter must (accurately) measure *instantaneous* current and voltage at a rate much higher than the waveform frequencies, multiply them together and then average the result over many samples. Depending on the waveforms being measured this can be surprisingly difficult.

Another method is to measure input power and subtract controller loss estimated by eg. simulating its performance with a similar load. Controller loss is usually small so the estimation doesn't have to be very accurate.

Comment: Thanks Bruce! In your last paragraph, you mean that I could use a bench power supply plugged into the wall through a watt meter? And then subtract controller losses from the power used by the bench power supply?

Comment: The wattmeter has to go between the power supply and controller, measuring DC power. Or you could just use a voltmeter and ammeter  (with both measurements taken 'simultaneously') and multiply volts x amps to get watts. Several years ago I [built my own wattmeter](http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/wattmeter.html) to analyze DC motors.

Answer (score 0):

The power of a motor is usually measured on the shaft. The mechanical performance is indicated on the nameplate. Just by the way.

Regardless of whether the motor is operated with direct current or alternating current, the power can e.g. measure the voltage on channel 1 with an osilloscope and the current on channel 2 and then multiply the two values from the oscilloscope. This also takes into account the power that the motor (as a generator) feeds into the supply network. In this case as a negative power.

All you have to do is note that a normal osilloscope is grounded and therefore you cannot do this without differential probes.

Of course you can make your life easier by using a power quality analyzer, for example.